# Kafka Debezium MariaDB SinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, debezium

Would anyone know how to pass a dynamic parameter in the SinkConnector connector instead of passing a static value (example below):

```
"transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.field":"messagesource",
"transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.value":"Debezium CDC from MySQL on asgard"
```

I'm searching how to pass a dynamic value, as the use of Debezium in our use-case is to replace a trigger, so we need to replace its rules too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the value you want to pass? There are Single Message Transform to insert things like the topic name

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I'm trying to add a type query that has been done in DB1 and the event's date, the only way I had was to include the query type based on the binlog, but the mysql version used does not allow me to do this